# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage with part of master visible on detail

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to push (make visible) little part of master page to detail page like on pictures in links below. Is it possible in Xamarin.Forms?
[Before swipe](https://www.programosy.pl/download/screens/13917/android-e-podroznik-1_s.png)
[After swipe](https://www.instalki.pl/components/com_djacatalog/images/13354_2_epodroznik.pl.jpg)

I'll be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```

Place a StackLayout or Grid that looks like the side menu shown in your image. Add a tap gesture recognizer to it.

```
slMenu.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
     Command = new Command(() => ShowSideMenu(masterPage)),
});


private void ShowSideMenu(MasterDetailPage masterPage)
{
    masterPage.IsPresented = !masterPage.IsPresented;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but requires quite some work, since you can't access the width of the MasterDetailView directly.

In another post (see [How to set width for MasterDetailPage in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400002/how-to-set-width-for-masterdetailpage-in-xamarin-forms/49997659#49997659) ) I have described how to change the width of the MasterDetail view. 
While implementing that, I came across a behaviour like you want to have, though for me it was an error.

Basically the steps would be

- Implement a custom version of the MasterDetail view where you can set up a custom width
- Change the width of the master view so it is a bit wider than it should be
- Adapt the calculations when collapsing and expanding the view so that they don't collapse the entire width

For instance if your Master View gets a width of 340 and you want the last 40 to show, make sure that when being collapsed it "only" moves by 300