# Is there any way to set the width of MasterDetailPage.Master in Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there any way to set the width of MasterDetailPage.Master in Xamarin? I want to decrease the width of the Menu Drawer. Hope you can help me with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  x:Class="DemoApp.MenuPage"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoApp.Views"
                  MasterBehavior="Popover"
                  NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
                  NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="MenuPage">
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Button Text="Home"/>
                    <Button Text="Login" Clicked="Login_Clicked"/>
                    <Button Text="Logout"/>
                    <Button Text="Exit"/>
                </StackLayout>    
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:Login/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>        
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>  

</MasterDetailPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom renderer.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/62894/#Comment_62894

Or use this solution

[How to set width for MasterDetailPage in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400002/how-to-set-width-for-masterdetailpage-in-xamarin-forms)